# Dynamics CRM Solution Import via SDK is not working

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I have the below code that imports a solution into CRM Dynamics.

The code executes successfully and the import job data returns a result of success. How ever when I look for the solution in Settings->Solutions it is not there. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
private void ImportSolution(string solutionPath)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(solutionPath);
        var request = new ImportSolutionRequest()
        {
            CustomizationFile = fileBytes,
            ImportJobId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        var response = _settings.DestinationSourceOrgService.Execute(request);

        var improtJob = new ImportJob(_settings);
        var importJobResult = improtJob.GetImportJob(request.ImportJobId);

        var data = importJobResult.Attributes["data"].ToString();
        var jobData = new ImportJobData(data);

        var filePath = $@"{this._settings.SolutionExportDirectory}\Logs\";
        var fileName = $@"{filePath}{jobData.SolutionName}.xml";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, data);

        PrintResult(jobData.Result, jobData.SolutionName);

    }

public class ImportJob
{
    private readonly ConfigurationSettings _settings;

    public ImportJob(ConfigurationSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public Entity GetImportJob(Guid importJobId)
    {
        var query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "importjob",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("importjobid", "data", "solutionname"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
        };


        var result = _settings.DestinationSourceOrgService.Retrieve("importjob", importJobId, new ColumnSet("importjobid", "data", "solutionname", "progress"));

        return result;

    }
}
```

Thre ImportSolutionResponse does not contain any information as per the screen shot below.
[image]

Comment: You have `var response = _settings.DestinationSourceOrgService.Execute(request);` what does `response` say ? You are not looking inside it

Comment: added a screenshot of the watch window after a response has been returned. Unfortunately it does not contain any information.

Comment: The import is only completed when the importjob record has the completed on date filled.